# How to customize the click event of dynamically created buttons from string array?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, dynamically-generated

Here is the code I have:

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddNewButton()

End Sub

Public Sub AddNewButton()

    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100

    For Each item As String In Globals.candidates
        Dim btn As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
        btn.Location = Location
        btn.Text = item
        btn.Width = 150
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.buttonClick
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        buttonTop += 20      
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub buttonClick()

    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Did you select {0} ?", ???????????), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No pressed")
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Globals.candidates is a global string array variable that holds a name "LastName, FirstName" and when the form is loaded I call the AddNewButton() Sub and it creates buttons for each item in the string array. No problem.

If you see in my code the "??????????" section, I don't know how to reference the dynamically created buttons's text so that I can display the proper "Did you select thisButton.text" properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Code changed as per suggestions: (Working)

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddNewButton()

End Sub

Public Sub AddNewButton()

    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100

    For Each item As String In Globals.candidates
        Dim btn As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
        btn.Location = Location
        btn.Text = item
        btn.Width = 150
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.buttonClick
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        buttonTop += 20      
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub buttonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Did you select {0} ?", btn.Text), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No pressed")
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the proper signature on your event handler:

```
Private Sub buttonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Then, you can use the `sender` object (which will be whichever button was clicked)

```
Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Did you select {0} ?", button.Text), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

Comment: So, I just make an empty Private Sub buttonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) and add the DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button) to my code?

I have updated my code to reflect everything on the entire form. The form works great as is, the only issue is getting the button's text in the string format.

Comment: Yes.  Have you not tried it yet?  As you can see in my example, once you cast the `sender` to the `Button` type, then you can access its `Text` property (and any of its other members).

Comment: I have changed the 3 lines of code you suggested however in the Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button) line it tells me, "sender is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: Because you didn't add it as a parameter to the method signature as I described (As did Steve in his answer as well).

Comment: I updated the code above to reflect the changes I believe you wanted made. This is where the error comes from from my previous comment. What am I doing wrong? I apologize for the ignorance.

Comment: The part where you cast the `sender` is supposed to be in the `buttonClick` method.  Not in the loop where you are creating the buttons.

Comment: You seem to be in over your head.  I recommend that you take a few steps back and learn more of the basics about events, event handlers, scope, and casting before you continue any further.  Its never a good idea to copy code into your project that you don't understand.

Comment: That works. Sorry about my ignorance. I am still newbie.

Comment: That's ok.  We all were once.  Just try to slow down and learn one concept at a time.

Comment: As Steve said, once you get a good grasp on Types and Casting, turn `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference to the button clicked you need to declare the event handler of the button click with the two parameters that are passed to it by  the form engine.

```
Private Sub buttonClick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
```

Now, this correct event handler receives a parameter named `sender` that is the control reference to the button clicked. You could cast it to a button and then extract the Text property

```
Private Sub buttonClick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)
    if btn IsNot Nothing then 
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Did you select {0} ?", btn.Text), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            MessageBox.Show("Yes pressed")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No pressed")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This should be enough in this simple case where you have just a string data, but, if you need to associate a more complex object (like an instance of a Person class for example) you could use the Tag property of every dynamically added button to store there a reference to the instance of the class

As a side note, your code works also without the declaration of the two parameters because you have the [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) configuration set to OFF. This is a bad practice because it introduces subtle errors in you parameters usage and in automatic conversions of type. If you are just starting with a new project remember to set its property Option Strict to ON

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect everything on the entire form. The form works great as is, the only issue is getting the button's text in the string format.

Comment: You need to change the signature of that buttonClick to use the REQUIRED parameters

Comment: This is not optional. Without the parameter declaration you cannot reference the button clicked